# How to override parent theme bootstrap class through the child theme

Tags: wordpress

Example- 
Parent theme

```
<div class="container-fluid">
</div>
```

What I want through without modifying the parent theme

```
<div class="container>
</div>
```

What will be possible best option to do that

Comment: copy the php file that contains the html you need to change into your child theme and modify it there.

Comment: Thanks @NickSurmanidze 
I have to do that way, I was looking if any way to use a filter hook

Comment: If you need to replace all container-fluids with contain, just override the css style for container-fluid in your child theme to act like container

Comment: @NickSurmanidze
actually not all of the container. It will differ based on page. I have decided to copy files to child theme to fix the  issue